# Drag an image from window in a wpf project to another window in a separate project?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I am very new to WPF and I've tried to find the guides and tutorials about this but haven't found exactly I wanted.

[This post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2e618697-fee6-4b40-bcee-3b2d28e71d68/wpf-drag-and-drop) has been the closest, a solution for moving an item between two different windows (in the same project). However this limits any other drag and drop features you want to do (e.g. within a canvas).

In a similar fashion, I want to move something (an image, within a listbox specifically) from one app to another (when both are running at the same time).

Any help or tips would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2e618697-fee6-4b40-bcee-3b2d28e71d68/wpf-drag-and-drop

Comment: Hi, I did provide a link to that in my post. This works within the same project between two different windows, but I'm looking for a solution for something between different projects.